# Changing time format using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to read 12h format time from file and replace it with 24 hour

example

> this is due at 3:15am -> this is due 15:15

I tried saving variables in regex and manupilate it later but didnt work, I also tried using substitution "/s" but because it is variable I couldnt figure it out

Here is my code:

```
while (<>) {
            my $line = $_;
        print ("this is text before: $line \n");
        if ($line =~ m/\d:\d{2}pm/g){
            print "It is PM! \n";}
        elsif ($line =~ m/(\d):(\d\d)am/g){
                print "this is try: $line \n";
            print "Its AM! \n";}
            $line =~ s/($regexp)/<French>$lexicon{$1}<\/French>/g;
            print "sample after : $line\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you expect `am` also change

Comment: please note that  `3:15am` != `15:15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script can do the work for you

```
$str="this is due at 3:15pm";
$str=~m/\D+(\d+):\d+(.*)$/;

$hour=($2 eq "am")? ( ($1 == 12 )? 0 : $1 ) : ($1 == 12 ) ? $1 :$1+12;
$min=$2;

$str=~s/at.*/$hour:$min/g;
print "$str\n";
```

Gives output as

```
 this is due 15:15
```

**What it does??**

- `$str=~m/\D+(\d+):(\d+)(.*)$/;` Tries to match the string with the regex

  - `\D+` matches anything other than digits. Here it matches `this is due at`
  - `(\d+)` matches any number of digits. Here it matches `3`. Captured in group 1 , `$1` which is the hours
  - `:` matches `:`
  - `(\d+)` matches any number of digits. Here it matches `15`, which is the minutes
  - `(.*)` matches anything follwed, here `am` . Captures in group 2,  `$2
  - `$` anchors the regex at end of
- `$hour=($2 eq "am")? ( ($1 == 12 )? 0 : $1 ) : ($1 == 12 ) ? $1 :$1+12;` Converts to 24 hour clock. If `$2` is `pm` adds `12` unless it is `12`. Also if the time is `am` and `12` then the hour is `0`
- `$str=~s/at.*/$hour:$min/g;` substitutes anything from  `at` to end of string with `$hour:$min`, which is the time obtained from the ternary operation performed before

Comment: This would convert 12:00pm (noon) to 24:00 wouldn't it?

Comment: @JimDavis i have edited my answer to take care of that

Comment: @Hussain I have added an explanation. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Thank you for your kindly response. And really thank you for your explanation. :):):):):)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Sorry for ask again. I'm getting confused at `$hour=($2 eq "am")? ( ($1 == 12 )? 0 : $1 ) : ($1 == 12 ) ? $1 :$1+12;`. Why you used `:`?

Comment: Its a ternary operator having syntax `? :` see the doc for more examples http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator. It acts as a short of `if else ` clause

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $values = time_12h_to_24h("11:00 PM");

sub time_12h_to_24h
{
    my($t12) = @_;
    my($hh,$mm,$ampm) = $t12 =~ m/^(\d\d?):(\d\d?)\s*([AP]M?)/i;
    $hh = ($hh % 12) + (($ampm =~ m/AM?/i) ? 0 : 12);
    return sprintf("%.2d:%.2d", $hh, $mm);
}
```

I found this code in the bleow link. Please check:
[Is my pseudo code for changing time format correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550361/is-my-pseudo-code-for-changing-time-format-correct)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it give what you expect

```
my @data = <DATA>;
foreach my $sm(@data){
if($sm =~/(12)\.\d+(pm)/g){
    print "$&\n";
}
elsif($sm =~m/(\d+(\.)?\d+)(pm)/g )
{
print $1+12,"\n";
}
}

__DATA__
Time 3.15am
Time 3.16pm
Time 5.17pm
Time 1.11am
Time 1.01pm
Time 12.11pm
```

Comment: I read online that $& is not a good idea, how do I save specific parts of the regex in variables